# Jquery replaceWith() inside loop with click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, events

im trying to replace various elements with another inside a jquery .each loop and give them on click events to their child nodes, but it does not work, here is my code.

```
var replacer = function () {
  var elementbody = "<div class='Container'><div class='Button'></div></div>";
  $('.myclass').each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).replaceWith(elementBody);
    $(element).find('.Button').click(function () {
  //------------------To do on click event------------------//
});
};
```

Comment: What is `$('.')` supposed to match? `.` has to be followed by a class name.

Answer (score 0):

After you use

```
$(element).replaceWith(...);
```

`element` still refers to the old element, not the elements that have replaced it. So `$(element).find('.Button')` doesn't find the button you just added.

Instead of adding the handler to each element that you add, use delegation to bind a handler just once, as explained in [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$("someSelector").on("click", ".Button", function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate as Barmar suggests or you could provide yourself with a new jquery object that references your new content before running the `replaceWith`

Something like this, maybe:

```
new_element = $('<div><button>Hello World</button></div');
$(element).replaceWith(new_element);
new_element.find('button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: seems nice, i will try this. Thanks.